# iOS 7 UINavigationController NavBar per controller color animation

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uinavigationbar

Is there any way to have different `barTintColor` of `UINavigationController`'s `UINavigationBar` on different pushed controllers **with smooth color transition animation**?

I'd like to have a smooth animation of `UINavigationBar`'s tint color during `UINavigationController`'s push/pop animation *and ideally also* interactive pop (gesture based controller pop).

Why do I need this? I'd like to have 1 controller in the navigation stack to have different tint color indicating status of some task (red / green etc.).

What I have tried so far:

- `viewWillAppear` (view lifecycle) methods, but there is no way to animate the `barTintColor` (like `setBarTintColor:animated:`)
- To change `barTintColor` in `[UIView animation...]` block, but that just weirdly animates frame of (probably) some background layer instead of smooth color transition.
- To change `barTintColor` in `[UIView transitionWithView:...]` block with `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve`, but that does not animate change. Just instantly changes to new tint color after the animation duration
- I had an idea of implementing new iOS 7 custom transition calculating and changing color of navbar during progress, but that seems to be big overkill (specially if I want to keep original animation appearance everywhere)

Thank you everyone for any ideas and answers

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't :-(

Comment: Try setting `barTintColor` inside the `viewWillAppear` method in _all_ view controllers. I had this issue when `barTintColor` was set only in the second controller. When set in all controllers, bar tint color is animated smoothly (didn't test interactive transitions though).

Answer (score 26):

You can get this by using `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator`.

1. Copy the example code to the `AController` and customize the colors.
2. Copy the example code to the `BController` and customize the colors.
3. That's it! During `UINavigationController`'s push/pop transition, the `AController`'s style will smoothly fade in/out to `BController`'s style.

Example code:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[self transitionCoordinator] animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

        // text color
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];

        // navigation items and bar button items color
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        // background color
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: How would you do it for IOS6?