# Set tintColor for UINavigationBar only for specific child view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, tintcolor

I have a basic master-detail app. Depending on the item that is selected in the master list, I'd like to set the `tintColor` of the navigation bar in the details view only.

I set the tint color like so: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = detailTintColor;` in `viewWillAppear:` of the details controller.

However, this also changes the color of the master controller's navigation bar to yellow (should remain red), which is visible as a flickering during the transition animation. I assume because there is only one navigation bar instance.

Here a screenshot to illustrate the problem:

- The "i" icon is in the master view controller's navbar and should be red, not yellow

[image]

Comment: Just noticed that your screenshot is from the iPhone simulator, but you're saying that you have a master-detail App. But UISplitViewController is not supported in iPhone, how are you implementing it?

Comment: @redent84 By master/detail I mean a master table and another "details" table view.

Comment: That's what I thought. You have to specify it clearly, as the implementations for iPhone and iPad are quite different.

Comment: This is how i did it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23301889/1388671

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 8 we set tint color by this :-

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

why not resetting to original color when view disapperars?

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = yourSavedColor;
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried this. The problem is already during the transition animation when switching to the details controller. The "i" icon of the master controller's navbar turns yellow, but should remain red (otherwise it flickers).

Answer (score 2):

You only have to change the tint color of the `UINavigationBar` in the Details `UINavigationController` in Storyboard:

[image]

Working sample:

[image]

You could use the `UIAppearance` API to obtain the same result by subclassing `UINavigationController`, and setting the details controller to be that custom class. Then, using UIAppearance API, set the `UINavigationBar` tint color:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[DetailNavigationController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in code without using `self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = color`? I don't know the color in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can use the `UIAppearance` approach.

Comment: I have an iPhone app (no split view). It's simply two table views.

Comment: This solution is only for iPad. Please refer to the other answers for iPhone environment.

Comment: Thank you for providing "appearanceWhenContainedIn" ! I use it very often now :)