# Swift transitionCoordinator() unexpectedly found nil error

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

I am trying to animate navigationBar.barTintColor smoothly, using transitionCoordinator() by following this example [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272698/ios-7-uinavigationcontroller-navbar-per-controller-color-animation/23301889#23301889). But while running on simulator produces **"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"** here's the code that I call in viewDidLoad:

```
var Coordinator = self.transitionCoordinator()
Coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ context in  //line of error
     self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = self.UIColorFromRGB(0x209624)
}, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

From Apple docs:

> The transition coordinator object associated with a currently active
>   transition or nil if no transition is in progress.

... and:

> If there is no in-progress transition associated with the current view
>   controller, UIKit checks the view controller’s ancestors for a
>   coordinator object and returns that object if it exists.

So, move your code to `viewWillAppear` where you can retrieve existing transition coordinator.
In `viewDidLoad` `self.transitionCoordinator()` returns `nil`.

Comment: Still same error! event after moving code to `override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) { ...`

Comment: my main navcontroller has a background color and child view navigation background color is transparent. I just wanted a smooth transition when navigating between ..

Comment: So, if same error appears then it means that there is no transition coordinator involved in transition to your view controller. How do you navigate/show/present your view controller?

Comment: I have two views and I use uinavigationController to navigate between tableview and my detail view, so while i'm in table view my navigation bar has a background and while i'm in detail view the navigation bar is transparent. the view with table is the one which is loaded first on application launch

Comment: Well, I resolved the problem by wrapping my transitionCoordinator() in an if condition, even though thank you.